# Nested string list with for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the two following nested lists

```
List 1: [["Bob", "Davon", "Alex"],["Dylan","Rose", "Hard"]] 

List 2: [["Red", "Black"] , ["Blue", "Green"], ["Yellow", "Pink"]]
```

And want to show the first word of each list within the nest together, the second etc. So that the outcome would be:

```
['Bob and Dylan', 'Davon and Rose', 'Alex and Hard'] --> for the first list

['Red and Blue and Yellow, 'Black and Green and Pink'] --> for the second list
```

So the first outcome I can get with the following code

```
name_list = [["Bob", "Davon", "Alex"],["Dylan","Rose", "Hard"]] 

def addition(name_list):    
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(name_list)):
        for j in range(len(name_list[i])):
            new_list.append(name_list[i][j] + " and " + name_list[i+1][j])
        return new_list       

addition (name_list)
```

But the second list: `[["Red", "Black"] , ["Blue", "Green"], ["Yellow", "Pink"]]` does not provide the right outcome.

Comment: The answers below both give the right idea, although I don't think they [explicitly](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEruWLwP7kAhVFsKQKHXT8ANoQFjABegQICxAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.python.org%2Fdev%2Fpeps%2Fpep-0020%2F&usg=AOvVaw0VpC2iB3EOvwvauPa37DN_) make the main point which should be that `zip(*my_list)` transposes your lists of lists into new versions which are then easy to manipulate into the detailed strings you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
names_list = ["{} and {}".format(*t) for t in zip(*name_list)]
colors_list = ["{} and {}".format(*t) for t in zip(*color_list)]
```

This probably won't work on python2.7 and you're better off upgrading to python3 anyways, since python2 is reaching end of life

Comment: Works fine in Python 2.7 for me.

Comment: There are three pair being zipped for color_list, so you actually need `["{} and {} and {}".format(*t) for t in zip(*color_list)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
[' and '.join(x) for x in zip(*name_list)]
[' and '.join(x) for x in zip(*color_list)]
```

`str.join()` will work on a list of any size, placing the string between each item.